# install the driver fail on Ubuntu 18.04 for Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)

Tags: drivers

After I installed Ubuntu 18.04 to my Levono MIIX 520, I cannot use the WiFi. I checked some info:

```
$ lspci    
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
$ dmesg | grep iwl    
[    4.064144] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: uCode file size 6882895 does not match expected size  
[    4.064295] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2   
[    4.072666] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: uCode file size 6857833 does not match expected size  
[    4.072819] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.072829] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2    
[    4.072836] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2  
[    4.072844] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2    
[    4.080565] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: uCode file size 6828649 does not match expected size   
[    4.080742] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no suitable firmware found!  
[    4.080746] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-7265D-22   
[    4.080748] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-7265D-29  
[    4.080750] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
$ ls /lib/firmware/ |grep iwl   
iwlwifi-3165-14.ucode  
iwlwifi-3165-29.ucode  
iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode  
iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode  
iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode  
iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode  
iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
```

I have deleted all iwlwifi related code file in `/lib/firmware`. Then I downloaded the drive form the Intel website and copied the two driver packages for Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 (starting from firmware XX.XX.13.0 and kernel 4.1) 4.2+ iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz to `/lib/firmware`.

Then, the Bluetooth works, but I can still not use the WiFi.

Downloading more driver packages form https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git doesn't help.